# Spring Data JPA: InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [web] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)];

Tags: spring, list, jpa, exception, jpql

I have an entity which has a list of strings. I want to search in that list with another list, for example: I want all topics with the specified list of tags. So basically, I want that my list of strings that I provide to be included in the list of strings that every entity has. Seems pretty simple, but I gen an error.

---

Topic entity:

```
public class Topic {
    // ...
    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "tags")
    private List<String> tags;
    // ...
}
```

---

Query in repository:

```
@Query("select t from Topic t where t.tags in (:tags)")
List<Topic> findAllByTags(@Param("tags") List<String> tags);
```

---

Test:

```
@Test
void findAllByTags() {
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("web", "mobile"));

    List<Topic> allByTags = topicService.findAllByTags(tags);
}
```

---

Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [web] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [web] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the tags:

```
@Query("select t from Topic t join t.tags tags where tags in (:tags)")
List<Topic> findAllByTags(@Param("tags") List<String> tags);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I tested this and the tests work, but when I try to call it in like a controller, it fails. Error: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s). It actually fails when I try it with more than 1 tag. Any ideas why?